# Multiple parameters for REST API

Tags: java, json, rest, swagger

Is this the right way to have multiple parameters for a REST API ?

```
@GET
@Path("/id/{userId,type,date}")
@Nullable
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
List<Exercise> findExercises(
        @ApiParam( value = "User ID", required=true) @PathParam("userId") Long userId,
        @ApiParam( value = "Type") @PathParam("type") String type,
        @ApiParam( value = "Date") @PathParam("date") String date);
```

If not, how can i accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is the right way :

```
@GET
@Path("/id/{userId}/{type}/{date}")
@Nullable
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
List<Exercise> findExercises(
        @PathParam("userId") Long userId,
        @PathParam("type") String type,
        @PathParam("date") String date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the path params as follows:
@Path("/id/{userId}/{type}/{date}")